# Middleware: Using C as the engine, Lua for Adapters...is this bad practice (Security risk)?

Tags: c, lua, middleware

I am an integration consultant and tend to use C and Lua in my spare time, unfortunately it is not my day job ;-(

Anyway, I tend to believe that a mixture of C and Lua is perfect for many "product" developments. I currently have an "adapter engine" built in pure C, but would like to actually move the adapter code to Lua....

For example, coding an EMAIL adapter in Lua is far easier than in C...yet I like the "engine speed of C"....

But now there is the big question of security risk in that the user can potentially add whatever he or she wants to the LUa scripts in production.....obviously there we could CHMOD the files...but is that really secure?

Ideally I want the C / Lua combination here....but now do I literally imbed the Lua code in the C application with a CHAR*....or do I issue a lua_dofile??

Thanks for the help

Lynton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, one of the drawbacks to using C/Lua in production is it tends to be harder to find resources who can develop for these languages.  C++ and JavaScript programmers are typically easier to find.

In terms of security, the key here is to use leading practices.  Security is about risk reduction, there is no expectation one can achieve perfect security so you need to mitigate risk.

Here are my suggestions:

- As with all middleware you need to use a hardened server.  This is the first step, if the server is compromised using any platform you are in trouble.  Middleware should *NOT* be in the DMZ.
- You want to store the Lua code external to the compiled code (otherwise you lose the advantage of using Lua.)  Make that storage as secure as you can.  CHMOD is good, a secure DB server is better.  The more secure the script store the more secure the system.
- You can encrypt the Lua source - this is a trade off since it makes it a little harder to gain the advantage of easy updates and modification.  You will probably need to implement decrypted script caching for performance.
- Your security is as strong as your weakest link.  If you provide a way to modify the Lua source via external access this will be an attack vector.  Avoid this design if you can.
- You should consider putting in change management checks.  For example a separate place in the system where a checksum for each Lua file is stored.  Then if an un-authorized change is made to a script you can abort functioning till the security breach is mitigated.

Other than the drawback I mentioned above, I don't think there is anything fundamentally flawed in your plan.  If it can aid in making a good middleware system I would say go for it.  Just mitigate the risk of your adapter scripts getting compromised as much as possible.

---

To expand on Donal's comment - given the popularity of [node](http://nodejs.org/) I would say that JavaScript is the **the** leading practice in scripted middleware right now.  If you can handle learning a new scripting language I would say it would be a good idea given the support, popularity, and tools available.

Comment: Server-side JS isn't _that_ common.

Comment: @DonalFellows I believe I said JS programmers were more common than Lua programmers -- didn't I?  Server side Lua middleware is less common than server side JS

Comment: I'm surprised that Lua's not made much impact in that area. If so, might be better off recommending Ruby. There's also quite a lot of people doing server-side Python, Perl and Tcl.

Comment: True, who can account for the fickle nature of programmers.  The advantage of node is async non-blocking, which can give good performance.  (There are some scaling claims -- but that remains to be seen IMHO)

Answer (score 0):

Your primary requirement in terms of security is to ensure that the server cannot evaluate anything send by clients *by any mechanism* (not just direct evaluation, but also through supplying filenames). A lesser requirement is that they should also not have any mechanism to produce a message that allows other clients to evaluate unexpected things (i.e., avoid XSS trouble). If you can satisfy these requirements, you've got a safe server and the language(s) that it written in won't matter; using multiple languages is in fact a good idea as it lets you leverage the best of each.

It's also a good idea to use a carefully configured firewall, plenty of privilege restriction, some kind of DMZ proxy system to at least verify basic syntactic legality of messages, etc. These things are all just good practice. (Aim to configure things so the server can only just manage to do the service you want to provide.)

With sending email, there are a few other things to beware of. In particular, you do not want to be a conduit for spam, so you need to take care to ensure that arbitrary email headers cannot be constructed from client input and that the data formats you send out are non-executable (or that the data is constructed in a way that is non-evil). Rate limiting is also a good idea; unless your site is insanely popular, you shouldn't need to send more than a few messages a second across all clients. If you're ever sending only to a small set of addresses (e.g., to a fixed contact address) then you can relax these restrictions a bit (but still be careful of header injection). In all cases, route all email by a specialist email handling server instead of doing routing yourself as this avoids a whole lot of configuration difficulties.

Comment: Great answer, but I question the first paragraph.  It ignores external influences -- if the scripts are stored in the clear it increases risk they can be accessed external to the system (eg OS zero day flaw).  This should be taken into account when designing a system to reduce risk.

Comment: @Hogan: The reason you have the DMZ system is to stop 0-day OS problems, by reducing the exposure set to just syntactically correct messages in the supported protocols. If you're too paranoid to put the code on disk, you should also be too paranoid to put it in memory even in compiled form, and that's just ridiculous. (What's more, stealing the code is usually not the most significant problem in the first place.)

Comment: Huh?  Who is worried about stealing the code?  I'm talking about modifying the scripts using the OS as a vector.  You first paragraph does not mention protecting from that.